# Debian 11.6.0 i386 doesn't boot after I updated VirtualBox to VirtualBox 7.0.6

Tags: debian, boot, kernel-panic

I've updated VirtualBox to the version 7.0.6. Now, my 32-bit Debian virtual machine doesn't boot anymore. Here is what I get when I start it:
[image: Kernel Panic]

I've tried to re-install Debian from CD, but the installer also crashes with the same error message. What should I do? I've installed many Linux programs on my Debian virtual machine and I don't want to lose them all and have to install them again.